# Bootstrap thumbnail slider, white space after last thumbnail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap thumbnail slider, I am showing images with 6 images on each row. but in total I have 7 images, the first row displays 6 images fine but then the last image displays with blank space. how do i remove that space? please help, below is the code

```
 <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" style="margin:10px "><strong>Menu</strong></h5>
                <div id="multi-item-example" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        @if(is_null($brands['menuItem']))
                            <p class="text-danger" style="margin-left: 20px">no menu items.</p>
                        @else
                        @foreach(($brands['menuItem'])->chunk(6) as $menuItem)
                            <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}">
                                @foreach($menuItem as $item)
                                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 float-left">


                                            <a href="#">
                                                <img src="/storage/{{$item->image}}" alt="Image"
                                                        class="img-fluid">
                                            </a>
                                            <br>
                                            <h6 style="text-align: center;">RM{{$item->price}}</h6>

                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev"  data-target="#multi-item-example" role="button"
                       data-slide="prev" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 3%; opacity: 1; height: 87%;">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 3%; opacity: 1;
                    height: 87%;" data-target="#multi-item-example" role="button"
                       data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: thats the last image with blank space]

Comment: I would keep the white space and align all images to the center of the container; so that if just one is shown, it will appear in the center of the container

Comment: I'd first use the browser developer tools (F12) and make sure the rendered html conforms to BS specs for the carousel and make sure all tags pair up and that you didn't generate too many items.